# How to prevent auto-opening console on execution in Windows?

Tags: windows, console

Premise: I'm very very new to Windows programming.

So far every small program I compiled, at the moment of the execution (...double click from the GUI) opens automatically a console where it prompts the std output.

Here is a screen-shot which shows the execution of [this example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Window_Creation#An_Example)

[image]

As you can see, behind the window created by the program there is a console.

Why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: You created a console mode project.  Whose entrypoint is main(), not WinMain().  Fall in the pit of success with the right project template to get started, use "Win32 Project".  You'll get some auto-generated code that already does what you are doing, just delete it if you want to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows programs come in two subsystems: windows or console. When you start a console program, a console is automatically created (if it does not exist already). Since console is the default, you have to set the appropriate linker option `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` when building your program.

There is no fundamental difference between the two subsystems. Windows programs can create a console and console programs can create windows, so you end up with both a window and a console.

There are more subsystems but they are not relevant to your question. For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx (also contains information about setting the linker option in Visual Studio)